# Android - How to change order of / re-arrange launcher icons for an app?

Tags: android, android-launcher

My app has four launcher icons which seem to be automatically displayed on the device's "Apps" screen in alphabetical order.

Is it possible for me to programmatically change the order in which they are displayed?

I have tried changing the order these activities feature in the manifest, but they still appear in alphabetical order on the device's Apps screen.

Comment: please provide screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible to change the order of icons in the "Apps" screen. That is fully controlled by the launcher application being used.